# Why does my Fedora has multiple boot loader entries

Tags: linux, fedora, boot-loader

Currently my Fedora when i login ,it shows below options and i have to choose option3 fast,else system goes into panic mode.

[image: boot loader options]

When i initially installed Fedora and also till few days back..it didn't gave me this options..It is very confusing,why all of a sudden ,it is presenting me these options.

After some search,i found those same entries in /boot/loader..but i am not sure ,if i can delete them,since it took me long time to finally configure system to my liking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each entry corresponds to a different version of the kernel. Here, the versions are 5.15.11, 5.15.10, and 5.14.10.

Kernel updates are installed along with regular package updates. However, new versions of kernels are installed side-by-side instead of replacing existing versions. This is to facilitate an easy rollback. If a new kernel version is found to be unsuitable for any reason, you can go back to the old version by simply selecting the right entry from the boot menu.

You can modify the boot menu and configure the default entry from which the system boots. You can also increase the time for which the menu is displayed. These changes are described in the Fedora docs: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f35/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/#sec-Configuring_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader

Comment: The problem is and that's why I didn't venture to answer is that Fedora normally keeps just the last two installed kernel releases while the OP has three which is mighty weird.

Comment: Thanks for the help..i am very to Linux world..i was able to set index1 as default entry ..though not sure why it was not taking new version